# Connect python to teradata without the driver, on unix

Tags: python, python-3.x, teradata, teradatasql

I am using python 3.x and unix for accessing teradata. I am totally new to teradata and python. I could easily connect to oracle with python but for teradata there is this no driver issue coming. I will not be able to do any unix side installations due to company policy. Can you please suggest ant work around where i can connect to the teradata using python without any drivers, i know i may sound foolish, but thats what my situation is. TIA

Comment: Without an appropriate driver, you can't connect to any database. Some packages do bundle certain drivers / dialects. For Teradata you need the _teradatasql_ driver or _teradatasqlalchemy_ dialect (if you are using SQLAlchemy) or  the full _teradataml_ package. Or you can use something like _pyodbc_ but then you would also have to install a Teradata ODBC driver, outside of the Python environment.

Comment: You can use Teradata REST API to connect to Teradata. - Newer Vantage Analyst has the API build-in. If you don't have such, Teradata provides a "QueryService" (former "REST Service") software you can install on any server. With the QueryService you'll have a server in between providing REST API and connecting to Teradata RDBMS. You just need some piece of hardware to run the service and your Teradata representative will be happy to provide the software for QueryService.

Comment: You need a thin jdbc driver as a single file from the Teradata web site, place it locally in your home directory and add that directory to your CLASSPATH env. variable.

Answer (score 0):

As Fred said, Teradata offers a *Teradata SQL Driver for Python*.

Here is a link to the documentation: https://github.com/Teradata/python-driver

Install the driver with: `pip install teradatasql`